# collapsing for border menues

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a side where four menus are on every border, they should be pushed out of the screen, and return as soon as the user hovers over the element. It works well for the left and right side, but not for top and bottom, Firefox let them move once you hovered over the element, Chrome and IE are not doing anything.

Here the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D3-BC</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="./resurces/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="./resurces/css/positioning.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper" id="header_wrapper">
            <div id="header">HEADER</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper" id="left_wrapper">
            <div id="left">LEFT</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper" id="right_wrapper">
            <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper" id="bottom_wrapper">
            <div id="bottom">BOTTOM</div>
        </div>
           <div id="graph_wrapper">GRAPH WRAPPER</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

First CSS:

```
body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #383838;
    background-image: url("../images/dark_wood.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

And here the second CSS:

```
#header, #bottom, #left, #right{
    background-color: #808080;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#left_wrapper, #bottom_wrapper, #right_wrapper, #header_wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FF00FF;
}
#header_wrapper, #bottom_wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}
#left_wrapper,#right_wrapper{
    height: 100%;
}
#header_wrapper{
    top: 0px;
}
#bottom_wrapper{
    bottom: 0px;
}
#left_wrapper{
    left: 0px;
}
#right_wrapper{
    right: 0px;
}
#left, #right{
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#header, #bottom{
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#left{
    left: -50%;
}
#left:hover{
    left:0px;
}
#right{
    right: -50%;
}
#right:hover{
    right: 0px;
}
#bottom{
    bottom: -50%;
}
#bottom:hover{
    bottom: 0px;
}
#header{
    top: -50%;
}
#header:hover{
    top: 0px;
}
```

Btw. the `display: inline-block;` changes nothing. Here it is online [online](http://d3-bc.feirell.de/).

I hope someone knows a little trick to get this working.
**I found out that when I change the ´-50%´ for the standard value to a pixel value it works. But why not with the percental value, like it workes for the left and right side ?**

Greetings, Feirell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The percentages of an element with `position: absolute` are relative to their parent sizes. This happens to look okay for your left and right elements, but the top and bottom divs don't appear to have any height at all. If you manually set a height to them it will work.

A better way to move an element in a percentage of its own dimensions is to use the `transform` property. You already use that to center them, so why not combine them to move the elements off the screen as well?

```
#header {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#footer {
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
#left {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#left {
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

And get rid of all the `left: -50%` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The percent system doesn't work because the parent doesn't have a height (so will take enough height to show the content inside). So the percent has no base. You can either give the parent a height:

```
#header_wrapper{
    height: 20px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

or use pixels instead of percent as you mentioned.

Comment: Ok yeah that worked but @Stephan suggested a even better answer.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Stephan the awsner should look like this:
Or see it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150502180455/http://d3-bc.feirell.de/) online.

```
#left_wrapper, #bottom_wrapper, #right_wrapper, #header_wrapper{
    position: absolute;
}
#header, #bottom, #left, #right{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#header_wrapper, #bottom_wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}
#left_wrapper,#right_wrapper{
    height: 100%;
}
#header_wrapper{
    top: 0px;
}
#bottom_wrapper{
    bottom: 0px;
}
#left_wrapper{
    left: 0px;
}
#right_wrapper{
    right: 0px;
}
#left, #right{
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#header, #bottom{
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#left{
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#left:hover{
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
#right{
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
#right:hover{
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
#bottom{
    transform: translate(-50%,50%);
}
#bottom:hover{
    transform: translate(-50%,0);
}
#header{
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
#header:hover{
    transform: translate(-50%,0);
}
```